# prove that f' is not increasing in interval that contain zero

Tags: calculus

We have question with this information:

$f(x) = x + 2x^{2}\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ if $x \neq 0$
$f(x) = 0$ if $x = 0$

It's easy to prove $f'(0) = 1$ with definition of derivative.
We want to show that any interval containing $x = 0$ also contains point where $f'(x) < 0$, so if cannot be increasing on such an interval.

**My answer:**
$f'(x) = 1 + 2(2x\sin{\frac{1}{x}} - \cos{\frac{1}{x}})$ if $x \neq 0$

I know that $2\sqrt{4x^2 + 1}+1 \le f'(x) \le -2\sqrt{4x^2 + 1}+1$ so it is obvious that $f'(x) < 0$ for some point but how can I show that is happen in interval that contain zero?

I'm sorry if my English is not good enough. Is it possible to help me? Thanks.

Comment: This should be obvious from expression for $f'(x) $. Just try to see what happens when $x\to 0$.

Comment: I add some information to question.

Comment: Since $f'(x) =4x\sin(1/x)+1-2\cos(1/x)$ we can see that the first two terms together tend to $1$ and last term oscillates between $-2$ and $2$ as $x\to 0$. Your desired conclusion follows.

Comment: Oh. thanks for answer. I don't check limit of that! but I can't vote for you.